# comparing modified versions of filenames obtained using VBA's FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

Using VBA with a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  I'm trying to compare filenames in two different directories, to find whether or not the same file is in both directories.  However, I'm not looking for an exact match; I'd like to strip certain types of prefixes off, so, e.g., `A-12234.pdf`, `12234.pdf`, and `A_  12234.pdf` should be considered equal to each other.

Let's say I have a function `stripPrefix()` that performs the necessary string operations to change a filename into a version that can be compared with others--in the prior case, `stripPrefix()` would return `12234.pdf` for all 3.  Then I could compare filenames in directories `c:\dir1` and `c:\dir2` using the following code:

```
sub findMatchFilenames()

dim fso as fileSystemObject
dim dir1 as folder
dim dir2 as folder
dim file1 as file
dim file2 as file

set fso=new fileSystemObject
set dir1=fso.getfolder("c:\dir1")
set dir2=fso.getfolder("c:\dir2")
for each file1 in dir1.files
 for each file2 in dir2.files
  if stripPrefix(file1.name)=stripPrefix(file2.name) then
   debug.print file1.name & " matches " & file2.name
  end if
 next file2
next file1

end sub
```

Big problem here: I'm calling `stripPrefix()` for the same filenames in `dir2` every time I iterate the `for..next file1` loop.  I could build arrays `dir1Array` and `dir2Array` of stripped versions of each filename, but it seems I can't correlate them with the `Files` collections in `dir1` and `dir2` because `Files` collections don't have numerical indexes.  I know because I tried using:

```
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set folderObj = fso.GetFolder("c:\data")
fileCount = folderObj.Files.Count
For c = 1 To fileCount
    MsgBox c & " " & folderObj.Files(c).name
Next
```

and got an "Invalid procedure call or argument" from `folderObj.Files(c).name`.  I suppose I could increment a counter as I go in the `for..next` loops and use the counter to refer back to the array, like:

```
'after creating arrays of stripPrefix() for dir1 and dir2
ctr1=0
for each file1 in dir1.files
 ctr2=0
 for each file2 in dir2.files
  if dir1array(ctr1)=dir2array(ctr2) then
   debug.print file1.name & " matches " & file2.name
  end if
  ctr2=ctr2+1
 next file2
 ctr1=ctr1+1
next file1
```

but that seems really clunky.  Is there a better way to handle this filename comparison operation?

Comment: I think this kind of clunkiness is what comes from using VBA I'm afraid. If you can (or could) shell out to Python or similar it would be much much easier.

Comment: @Vicky, unfortunately this is a macro that I'm going to have to distribute to other users who may not have Python installed.  Anything I call outside of VBA would need to be part of a standard XP/Win7 distribution.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff in this question. I for one can't wrap my head around it. What are you asking exactly? You may want to consider making your question more succinct, focusing on your main point. Such a question will likely attract more help.

Comment: @Jean-François, basically I'm trying to compare the filenames of two directories, where I'm actually comparing the strings returned by passing filenames to string manipulation functions.  Trying to avoid calling the string manip. functions too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make a dictionary object of directory 2 and then search that using directory 1. You can strip off the prefixes when inserting into the dictionary object.

Only problem is, you might not then have a unique filename in the dictionary

For example A-12345 would be the same as A12345 after stripping the prefix

Comment: thanks for the tip about the dictionary object--i never knew it existed.  I'll study up on it and see if it will work for this.

Comment: works well, thanks.  I'm matching two dictionaries against each other, each using the initial name as the key and the stripped version as the value.  once I find a match between values, I can use the values' keys to retrieve the matching files from dir1 and dir2's .Files collections.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the use of wildcards through using DIR?

Something like (not tested):

```
myFile = Dir("C:\*1234.pdf")
Do While myFile <> ""
If myFile <> "." And MyFile <> ".." Then
Msgbox myFile
End If
MyFile = Dir 
Loop
```

Put this into an array. And you can do the same for the other directory as well, then compare the two arrays.

Comment: This looks pretty simple.  I'll see if this works and compare it to the dictionary object solution given above.